# Docker app not able to access MySQL running in another container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, lamp, testlink

I am trying to bring up a dockerized instance of Testlink (LAMP application) and connect it to an instance of MYSQL running in another container.

```
$ sudo docker network create mynetwork
```

Instantiate the container with MySQL

```
$ docker run -d --name mysql -p 3306:3306 --network mynetwork -v /Users/dockervol/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e 'MYSQL_ROOT_NAME=root' -e 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password' mysql
```

Instantiate the container with Testlink

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 --network mynetwork --name testlink suzukishunsuke/testlink
```

When I access http://localhost/testlink and follow the standard installation tests it seems to work. The two containers are linked but when testlink tries to login to mysql it says Access denied.

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'156.18.0.2' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Well, it's not docker. Are you sure that the  user 'root'@'156.18.0.2' has access? Or that it's covered via a wildcard?

Comment: @NickBurke, it has some relation with docker (it is the docker entrypoint who sets the root password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that the `mysql` image only set the password that you provide with that environment variable when it starts for the first time (when it initializes its data directory).

So, *if you think that this is your case*, empty your mysql data volume (loosing the data) and start it again, *or* set the root password manually.